# What is the policy on questions that ask how to crack passwords?

Tags: discussion, flags, scope, legal, ethics

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23851857/how-to-convert-hashed-password-to-readable-password) post, the OP is asking how to "convert these hashed passwords to readable passwords." Since this is not a forum for black hat hackers, I would expect the question to be deleted. As it stands it has been marked as a duplicate, but the question is still visible. It has 5 answers, all of which basically state that this is impossible, which is odd since hash cracking techniques are well known.

The OP answered his own question by locating a rainbow table site and cracked the one hash that he posted, although his answer no longer appears due to multiple downvotes. I was the only commenter that pointed out that it's unethical to crack your user's passwords. Another commenter observed that the hash appeared to be an unsalted MD5 hash, which is bad and that the hash should be upgraded, which at least seems constructive.

I have flagged for moderator attention, but the flag still shows active. What is the proper response to this type of question?

Comment: The funny thing is that in reality that question shouldn't be all that problematic since the answers should simply be "that's going to be practically infeasible given that ...". Unless of course we're talking unsalted MD5 ...

Comment: I believe there is a lot of old technology out there that is vulnerable to simple attacks. The OP actually has over 3K rep and his previous questions don't show any nefarious intent. Perhaps I should have pushed him harder on why he wanted to do this, but no one else did. So all I could think of was a flag.

Comment: Don't answer it if you don't like it; downvote it if it makes you feel better but I don't see why it should be offtopic simply because it is perceived unethical. Perhaps the company's future depends on an old password that's only found inside that database, who knows?

Comment: @Jeroen there are many a results for a search of "crack md5"

Comment: On the other hand, wouldn't it be wonderful if someone posted a simple question on how to crack some sort of security scheme and then it got cracked within minutes or days, and then someone showed whoever came up with these security measures what happened?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The proper action on questions which might show nefarious intent cannot be generalised.
**Take each post on its own merits.**

Naturally, this question was already asked long before the meta-split, so read here for all the details and a great answer: [Dealing with questions of nefarious intent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3528/dealing-with-questions-of-nefarious-intent)

Comment: The linked answers are actually very good.