# Official SO policy on answering questions related to Web scraping

Tags: discussion, legal, scraping

I would like to know what is the SO policy on answering questions related to the web scraping (crawling and similar procedure). As an SO user, I am always ready to answer questions relating to web scraping. But, I often see the warning (as comments under the OP) such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31062884/scraping-javascript-with-rcurl) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30954403/extract-values-from-webpages/30954467#30954467).

*You and anyone who helps you are in violation of... terms of service... and face potential legal action.*

That sounds very scary for answering those questions.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267699/how-do-we-handle-questions-that-are-potentially-or-blatantly-illegal-or-maliciou and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291888/badly-phrased-and-morally-questionable-questions

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274906/should-questions-that-violate-api-terms-of-service-be-flagged

Comment: The bigger problem with the [scrape] tag and the like is that a spam ring is currently posting artificial, off topic questions there so that they can answer with spam for their products. I've deleted a series of accounts doing this over the last several days.