# Am I allowed to ask about cracking a forgotten Ethereum wallet keystore file password?

Tags: discussion, legal

I have an old Ethereum wallet keystore file that I created in 2017.

I can see that the address contains a tiny amount of eth, such a small amount that I'm wondering if it's worth my time, however I'm trying to recover it nonetheless, even if it's just as a programming exercise.

I found [a post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/91910/recovering-private-key-from-keystore-file) describing how to recover it if you know the password, however it uses node synchronous code, and I'm trying to convert it into asynchronous code, however I've run into some programming difficulties and I wanted to ask on Stack Overflow why my asynchronous code doesn't work properly.

Basically, I don't understand why the stack is processing all output before actually attempting each crack attempt, and I was going to paste some example code to illustrate what I misunderstand.

I've read several documents and YouTube videos about promises and event-driven programming, but I still don't seem to get it.

I've seen meta posts that ask about cracking files for forgotten passwords for Microsoft software saying that it's generally okay, but I'm unsure if this applies in my case.

It's a programming question, not a security question, so I figure that I shouldn't ask on Security.SE.

Is it ok to ask this question on Stack Overflow?

Comment: i have since found https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256139/what-is-the-policy-on-questions-that-ask-how-to-crack-passwords and since i believe i'm not doing anything unethical, i figure it's ok, but would be good to get some feedback

Comment: Related, maybe even a possible duplicate: [Should questions about programming viruses and malware be allowed?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262656)

Comment: Note: you asked two questions. You shouldn't do that as you start to ask too much of the answerers. Focus on your actual question, perhaps the other one isn't even relevant anymore when you learn where the goof is.

Comment: If your issue is with converting synchronous to asynchronous code, then you can and should remove as many other details as possible from the code (construct [a minimal, but complete, example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so it's easier to answer and more useful to others). This might even mean removing any mention of Ethereum 
or cracking passwords (neither of those things have anything to do with asynchronosity, but whether it's possible to have a question asking about your issue that makes sense without that is something you'll need to figure out).

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The key here is the focus of your post

- Asking how to access Ethereum accounts (i.e. "How do I get my account back?") is **off-topic**
- Asking how to break into someone else's account is **off-topic**
- Asking how to use NodeJS to access data in a local keystore file is **on-topic**

Comment: def using nodejs to access data in a local keystore file, so i figure i'm on topic; i'll accept this answer and ask my question vsoon

Comment: @loud_flash - You will likely want to provide both the synchronous code if you can (if you can reduce it to a minimal example), then provide the asynchronous code (again minimal example) that isn't working, just remember SO isn't a code writing service.

Comment: @loud_flash: I predict that this is actually a complete non-issue, because by the time you are finished creating a [mre], it is highly likely that anything related to cracking and Ethereum will be gone, since it is not actually relevant at all to the problem of asynchronous vs. synchronous programming. I also have a suspicion that, by the time you have created a MRE, your question will be a duplicate of a question that has already been answered.

Comment: well, i posted it, but it got buried with no answers or comments, probably because i didn't compact it enough: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70596875/why-is-all-of-my-output-appearing-before-each-brute-force-attempt-when-attemptin

Comment: @loud_flash - So edit the question and improve it.

Comment: @loud_flash yes your question as written is more of a forum-question than a stackoverflow-question. A key skill to learn when posting SO questions is distilling your problem down to something specific, and removing irrelevant detail (which is also a great skill to have in general, often resulting in solving your own question). Try running some experiments with parts of your script, checking the outputs to see if they match what you expect, try running the synchronous code you found to see if it works before you convert it all, and convert it gradually to see when it stops working, etc.